# Smoke simulation not working in Blender 2.77a

Tags: smoke-simulation

I understand at least 100 people have asked this question before. I am going to be as specific as possible and provide a screenshot. I used "Quick Smoke" on a circle with an Ngon fill type. Nothing shows up. I stretch out the cache and the maximum frames available, it simply does not work. Rendered mode for internal and cycles, nothing shows. If anyone wants the .blend file, here, I will provide it, but I have *no* idea what I am doing wrong, and I am using an integrated CPU.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41482

What is missing or incorrect here? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set up the domain object as **Domain**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smoke starts after it has gone through all keyframes, you have yours at 10000, that will take a long time. Set the max to 100, press play and wait for it to start, then change it back to your desired amount. Oh, the top panel of your mesh behind the sphere's normal is inverted. :)

EDIT: And, as cegaton said, the domain has to be a domain object.

Comment: Another question, while I can: Editing the Domain and Flow colors does not edit the smoke color. Do I edit the color in the Node Editor? Add a node or something?

Comment: @Darknaviexe EDIT: Colour changing acts weirdly, i'm yet to fully understand. Also, it requires a light to be in the scene, try adding a Sun light.